# Fetch resources with relationship in azure using resource manager

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a cosmos DB, a queue, a function, a MySQL DB. The cosmos DB gets an entry, it writes into the queue. When it comes to queue automatically triggers a function which writes into DB. While fetching the resources from azure using resource manager, I got all the resources under the subscription, but could not find the relationship with these. Can I get the relationship between these?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11661) GitHub issue talks exactly about what you are looking for. Please have a look at the conversation. In short, we have feature called as [resource links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcelinks) which we can use to mark a relationship between resources and then query a resource for its linked resources however currently we can discover the related resources directly through a resource's properties or by tagging resources to note connections.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!